# Ruby integer always rounds to the nearest whole number and won't save decimal places

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a simple form  with an input for `fee` which is an integer. I want the input to be stored like money/prices are normally - to 2 decimal places - regardless of the input. If someone enters `5.1` into the form, I'd like it to show `5.10` in my view, for example. At the moment if I enter `5.1` it shows `5`. Regardless of what is entered into the form a whole number is returned.

Here is the _form code:

```
<%= simple_form_for @order do |f| %>

<%= f.input :start_point %>
<%= f.input :restaurant_location %>
<%= f.input :customer_location %>
<%= f.input :fee %>
<%= f.button :submit %>

<% end %>
```

and here is the code from my index view:

```
<% @orders.each do |order| %>
    <h4 class="order-info"><%= order.start_point %></h4>
    <h4 class="order-info"><%= order.restaurant_location %></h4>
    <h4 class="order-info"><%= order.customer_location %></h4>
    <h4 class="order-info"><%= order.fee %></h4>
    <%= link_to "Edit", edit_order_path(order) %>
    <%= link_to "Delete", order_path(order), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %>
<% end %>
```

If I write it as `'%.2f' % order.fee` it shows `5.00` in the view instead of `5.10`

Comment: What do you mean "fee which is an integer"? Do you mean your model has a `fee` field that is of the type `integer`?

Comment: `fee` is just the name of the column in the table, with datatype integer. Sorry if i'm not using the correct terminology - i'm relatively new to programming.

Comment: If the data type is integer, then you can only store an integer in it. If you want to store something else, then you'll need to change the data type. If you're using it to store money-like values, then consider a Big Decimal. You can Google around for the pros and cons of using different data types to store money values.

Comment: what datatype should be used for money?

Comment: If you want decimal place, database column type should be Big Decimal or Decimal as @jvillian said. Be sure not to use float. I doubt the problem is related with float or client side javascript.

Comment: Great, thanks! No idea why I thought it was a good idea to choose integer... Will change it to Decimal.

Comment: Just to be clear: It is fully possible and quite common to store monetary values as integers in databases. The values are stored in the type of currency (e.g. cents), so storing `3.05$` becomes `305` in the database.

Comment: @MarcinKołodziej - that's a *really good* point! In fact, I've used both. So, thank you for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your are storing your value in integer datatype you can change it in float to store and show values after decimal point write following migration and add following line to change the datatype in your migration.

```
rails g migration change_fee_to_be_float_in_orders
```

> and in your migration

```
class ChangeFeeToBeFloatInOrders
  def up
   change_column :orders, :fee, :float
  end

  def down
    change_column :orders, :fee, :integer
  end
end
```

Comment: will need `up` and `down` here to make migration reversible.